# can't find module 'cucumber'

Tags: node.js, protractor, cucumber

I have installed protractor and cucumber globally.

When I run this code using protractor:

```sh
$ protractor ./config/cucumber.conf.js
```

I get the following error:

```
[15:54:03] E/configParser - Error code: 105
[15:54:03] E/configParser - Error message: failed loading configuration file ./config/cucumber.conf.js
[15:54:03] E/configParser - Error: Cannot find module 'cucumber'
Require stack:
- D:\AutomationTesting\Cucumberbasics\node_modules\protractor-cucumber-framework\lib\cucumberLoader.js
- D:\AutomationTesting\Cucumberbasics\node_modules\protractor-cucumber-framework\index.js
- D:\AutomationTesting\Cucumberbasics\config\cucumber.conf.js
- C:\Users\Admin-asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\configParser.js
- C:\Users\Admin-asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\launcher.js
- C:\Users\Admin-asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\cli.js
- C:\Users\Admin-asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.module.exports.load (D:\AutomationTesting\Cucumberbasics\node_modules\protractor-cucumber-framework\lib\cucumberLoader.js:19:24)    
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\AutomationTesting\Cucumberbasics\node_modules\protractor-cucumber-framework\index.js:8:33)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)`enter code here`
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
```

Comment: `D:\AutomationTesting\Cucumberbasics\node_modules\protractor-cucumber-framework\lib\cucumberLoader.js` I think it's looking for a locally installed version of cucumber. try running `npm i --save-dev cucumber`

Comment: Why is there a `enter code here` in the stack trace?

Comment: This is a configuration error code. What is in your configuration? I think that would help understand what's going wrong here.